# Coincident enumeration of images in Lyx

Tags: beamer, graphics, lyx, enumerate

How can I enumerate a list of images, where each image is solely displayed within precisely the same coordinates on the Beamer page?

I was effectively doing this by duplicating slides; the first slide contains the first image and the second slide contains the second enumeration of image. Same *slideshow* effect but page numbers are inaccurate and worst of all there are tons of hard to manage frames since all other content must persist in all duplicated slides.

Comment: In other words, do you want to say something like `\UseImages{a,b,c,d}` and have them show up in the same spots on pages 1, 2, 3, and 4?

Comment: yes, except I'd like the page number to stay the same, such that it is like a transition effect while the rest of the page content remains

Comment: I've answered the question as best as it can be answered, I think, but if you're talking about having a *single* PDF page display different things depending on when buttons are clicked, etc., you're going to have a hard time. This is *technically* possible, but *very* few PDF readers support that part of the standard. The best you can get while maintaining portability is the duplicative approach I showed in my answer, the perhaps you can be smarter about the duplication itself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does an approach like this work?  You can use `\only<j>{duck}` to have `duck` appear only on part `j` of the frame.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \only<1>{\includegraphics[height=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \only<2>{\includegraphics[height=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \only<3>{\includegraphics[height=.5\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With `expl3` and `xparse`, it's easy to extract this into a beamer-friendly command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_ecoe_image_int
\clist_new:N \l_ecoe_image_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \UseImages { D<>{1} O{} m }
  {
    \int_gset:Nn \g_ecoe_image_int {#1}
    \int_gdecr:N \g_ecoe_image_int
    \clist_set:Nn \l_ecoe_image_clist {#3}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_ecoe_image_clist
      {
        \int_gincr:N \g_ecoe_image_int
        \only<\g_ecoe_image_int> { \includegraphics[#2]{##1} }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  The images will start on the second slide:

  \UseImages<2>[height=.3\textheight]{
    example-image-a,
    example-image-b,
    example-image-c
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will also work in arguments to other commands like `\parbox`:

```
\parbox{2in}{%
  \UseImages[height=.3\textheight]{
    example-image-16x10,
    example-image-16x9}}
test text
```

[image: parbox]

Comment: one follow up question: now that images are coincident, how do I keep text below it in a fixed position, irregardless of varying image sizes creating extra blank space?

Comment: @ecoe See edit :)